# How to use facet_wrap correctly in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I would like to use the facetting function, But the code runs an error. Reprex produces a plot without the facet_wrap line. The error obtained with facet_wrap is:
At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `Building.Age`.

- Plot is missing `Building.Age`
- Layer 1 is missing `Building.Age`
- Layer 2 is missing `Building.Age`

  ```r
  g %>% 
    count(Locality.Division = factor(Locality.Division), Number.of.Beetle = factor(Number.of.Beetle)) %>% 
    mutate(pct = prop.table(n)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = Locality.Division, y = pct, fill = Number.of.Beetle, label = scales::percent(pct))) + 
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') + 
    geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = .9),    # move to center of bars
              vjust = -0.5,    # nudge above top of bar
              size = 3) + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
    facet_wrap(~ Building.Age)+
    labs(title = "Comparison between Number of beetle, Locality division and Age of the building",subtitle ="Building age")
  ```

````
<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

    ``` r
count(g, Building.Age)
g$Building.Age
count(g, Number.of.Beetle)
g$Number.of.Beetle
count(g, Locality.Division)
g$Locality.Division
````

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It doesn't look like the dataset you are using for plotting has a variable named `Building.Age` in it. You calculate counts for `Locality.Division` and `Number.of.Beetle` for your plot. Maybe you want to add counts of these by building age?

Comment: Is this an issue just when using percentage representation of the plots. The plot for counts did work for the same dataset.

Comment: Possibly! :) You'll want to add an [example of your dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for folks to be able to see what is going on here. In terms of troubleshooting you could calculate the percentages in a separate step so you can examine what the dataset your are using in the plot looks like.

Comment: The question has been edited. I am a beginner in R. Kindly let me know if there is an issue